# Matplotlib: How to add another X-axis where the ticks correspond to the points on the graph with custom labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot data obtained from a script.
My code is something like this:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()

a = [10, 20, 30] # N Total Items
b = [1, 5, 10] # Time (s)
c = [2, 6, 7] # N items of lenght 1

ax.plot(a, b, '-m^')
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax2.set_xticklabels(c)
ax.set_xlabel("N Total Items")
ax.set_ylabel("Time (s)")
ax2.set_xlabel("N items of lenght 1")
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoP0l.png)

I want the C values to represent ticks that correspond to each of the points drawn on the graph. So, "2" would correspond to point (10, 1), "6" to point (20, 5), etc.

Is there any way to achieve this with matplotlib? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do so by aligning the axis limits and then replacing the tick-labels

```
ax.plot(a, b, '-m^')

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(a)
ax2.set_xticklabels(c)
```

[image]